# Setting checkbox values in Javascript based on nested values

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a follow up to this question [Javascript for nested 'Select all' checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445240/javascript-for-nested-select-all-checkboxes), I have a list of checkboxes with a 'Select All' option for every item, and a 'Select All' item for each group.

I set the checkboxes server side, and what I'd like to do is use JQuery to set the 'select all' checkboxes if the child checkboxes are selected when the page loads, and also to set the select all checkboxes if the child options are checked.

```
<fieldset>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkall"><strong> All</strong>
    </label>
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedLocations" class="chkChild checkall" value="China" />
            <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;China</strong>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedLocations" class="chkChild" value="Hong Kong" checked="checked" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hong Kong
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedLocations" class="chkChild checkall" value="Australia" />
            <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Australia</strong>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedLocations" class="chkChild" value="NSW" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NSW
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedLocations" class="chkChild" value="VIC" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VIC
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

I have a Select All checkbox that selects/deselects everything, and a checkbox next to each country (Australia and China in this example) that selects/deselects all the locations in that country, with the following code:

```
    $(function () {
        $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $('.chkChild').on('click', function () {
            if (!$(this).is('.checkall')) {
                $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.checkall').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: And what’s your actual problem with this?

Comment: If for example, a user checks on all the options under each country then for that country checkbox to be checked.  If all country check boxes are checked, then the top Select All option should then be checked.

Comment: That is what you _want_. What your _problem_ in implementing it is, you still haven’t told us.

Comment: I don't know where to start, my Javascript is quite poor! I believe I need to set a function on document.ready which mirrors my existing ones, but not sure of an elegant way to do this without duplicating code

Comment: If you don’t want to duplicate code, then use _named_ functions that you can refer to in different places, instead of anonymous ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').on('change', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        if($this.is('.chkChild')){
            $('.checkall:not(.chkChild)').prop('checked', $('.checkall.chkChild').not(':checked').length == 0)
        }
    });
    $('.chkChild:not(.checkall)').on('change', function () {
        var $fs = $(this).closest('fieldset'),
            $all = $fs.find('.checkall'),
            childstate = $fs.find('> label > input[type="checkbox"]').not('.checkall').not(':checked').length == 0;
        $all[childstate ? 'not' : 'filter'](':checked').prop('checked', childstate).change();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kbp5d/)

Comment: Exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct about what you want then this should do it.

```
$(function () {
    checkBoxes();
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $('.chkChild').on('click', function () {
        if (!$(this).is('.checkall')) {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.checkall').prop('checked', false);
        }
        checkBoxes();
    });
});

function checkBoxParents (jelem) {
    jelem.parents('fieldset')
    .find("> label > input[type=checkbox]:first")
    .prop('checked', jelem.prop('checked'));
}

function checkBoxes () {
    var any = false;
    $('.chkChild').each( function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            checkBoxParents($(this));
            any = true;
        }
    });
    if (!any) { $(".checkall").prop("checked", false); }
}
```

Comment: Not quite - you'll see that with your example if you click on just one of the children under "Australia", i.e., VIC, then Australia will be checked.  Australia should only be checked if BOTH NSW and VIC are checked